# Using the same activity for displaying different data (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on a simple quiz application for Android. It has 10 questions and displays them one by one. Each question has three options. When the user answers a question he's redirected to the next one. 
I'm not sure what's the right way to implement this. 
I guess I shouldn't make 10 different activities with the same look, just different text inside. 
Probably I should reuse the same one, but how? And if I do, how'd I know which one is the 10th one in order to display the score after answering that one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Listeners and an integer which contains the current question. You can use the switch from java to filter the value of the integer.

Answer (score 0):

You may make array of questions and answers , then make a button to navigate to next index of question and loop up to the size of arrays.